# Add to cart option to have multiple of 6

Tags: plugins

I am building a wholesale store with wordpress and woocommerce and having a strange problem with the requirement.

The client wants to sell the products in multiple of 6 like 6/12/18/24, 
so when a user reach product page , he can select 6/12/18/24 as product quantity.

I have tried variation of product but the problem is this will hide the orignal price of product and will show the price of 6 products at least.

For example:
 I have created variations for a product priced at 1$ with multiples of 6 and then it will show the price as "from 6$" rather than orignal price of product and its seems too much work to add variations in 500+ products manually.

How to add only multiples of 6 in the add to cart quantity selection?

Answer (score 1):

In the bleeding edge of WooCommerce 2.1 you can filter `woocommerce_quantity_input_min` and `woocommerce_quantity_input_step` directly. That should get you 6,12,18, etc. I have no idea if these filters are in WC2.0.?.  Note the $product object is passed to the filter in case you don't want this to be a universal change. You can get the bleeding edge of [WooCommerce from github](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce), though it probably isn't advisable to use it in production yet.

```
function wpa116693_filter_min_quantity( $min, $product ){
    return 6;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_min', 'wpa116693_filter_min_quantity', 10, 2 );

function wpa116693_filter_quantity_step( $step, $product ){
    return 6;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_step', 'wpa116693_filter_quantity_step', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: The filters you are using are there in `WC2.0`, additionally there is `woocommerce_quantity_input_max`. The filter  `woocommerce_quantity_input_args` pretty much bundles those - [woocommerce_quantity_input()](http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-woocommerce_quantity_input.html#672-693) in source. @user2844394

Comment: I just realized that it's working just fine, with both methods - singular or combined filter - *but* only for simple products. Before I just tried it on a variable product and there seems to be some interference with the `add-to-cart-variation.js`, causing the unwanted behaviour. @user2844394

Comment: That's odd, because the `quantity.php` template is the same for all product types.

Answer (score 0):

I had to look into that problem once, but the decision at the end was to sell in packages of 8, I never really had to solve the problem. Maybe that would be the easiest solution anyways?

I stumbled over a question on stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/a/17762213/2505105 explaining how to do it:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'pkg_wc_quantity_input_args', 10, 2 );
function pkg_wc_quantity_input_args( $args, $product ) {
    $args['input_value'] = 8;
    $args['max_value'] = 64;
    $args['min_value'] = 8;
    $args['step'] = 8;
    return $args;
}
```

The guy who wrote answer added a little bit more information, so best would be to go there yourself. *But* before you get all excited, this isn't working perfectly.

---

**Update:**

This method just as well as the one that @helgatheviking suggested is working, *but* only for simple products. The problem remains for variable products, see my comments at @helgatheviking's answer. In addition this does *not* take care of the quantity input inside the cart.

---

**2nd Update:**

Cleaning up I found this code again, it concerns implementing the steps on the cart page, for this you have to use `$_product`.

```
function wpse116693_filter_min_quantity_cart( $min, $_product ){
    return 6;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_min', 'wpse116693_filter_min_quantity_cart', 10, 2 );

function wpse116693_filter_quantity_step_cart( $step, $_product ){
    return 6;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_step', 'wpse116693_filter_quantity_step_cart', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: thanks for the amswer mate , i will test this and report my results here

min and max quantity plugin cant do what i need exactly , it can only limit products  but i want multiples as well

lol , and i got excited

Comment: OK , Now here is how achieved this 


there are 3 places where i want to replace the settings to take 6 as min value and rest provide multiples of 6 for rest of quantity values 

1. product page

Answer (score 0):

That is a good solution but it wont' work with variable products because those products input values are overridden using javascript. I spent a while putting a plugin together that now supports variable products that would be worth a try. It allows you to set minimum / maximum / step values for products and is pretty easy to use.

WooCommerce Advanced Product Quantities

http://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-incremental-product-quantities/

Answer (score 0):

I found your question when I was on some sort of same kind of mission.
At least in WooCommerce 3+ there are 2 ways needed to adjust the input number for products:

```
// Add quantity limit for simple products & on cart page
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', my_woocommerce_max_quantity', 10, 2 );
function my_woocommerce_max_quantity( $args, $product ) {
    $args['max_value'] = 10; // Max quantity
    return $args;
}

// Add quantity limit for variable products
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'my_woocommerce_max_quantity_variations' );
function my_woocommerce_max_quantity_variations( $args ) {
    $args['max_qty'] = 10;      // Max quantity
    return $args;
}
```

Now you have full control over the input arguments you could add the $args['....'] into your functionlets say:

```
$args['input_value'] = 1;   // Starting value
$args['max_value'] = 10;    // Maximum value
$args['min_value'] = 1;   // Minimum value
$args['step']    = 6;   // Quantity steps
```

It's an old topic but still, maybe this could still be used by someone.